# Capitalisation of "vi"

Tags: discussion

General usage seems to be that *vi* begins with a lower-case V, and that proper names that begin with a lower-case letter should continue to do so both in title-case contexts and at the start of sentences.

So shouldn't the name/headline of this site be **vi and Vim**?

Answer (score 2):

That looks decidedly *ugly* to me. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) seems to agree with you, however, so I'd suggest using **Vim and vi** instead.

Related posts on ELU:

- [How do you capitalize a proper noun such as “iPhone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/how-do-you-capitalize-a-proper-noun-such-as-iphone)
- [Capitalising a sentence whose first word is explicitly lowercase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28383/capitalising-a-sentence-whose-first-word-is-explicitly-lowercase)

Comment: But the [original manpage](http://ex-vi.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ex-vi/ex-vi/vi.1?revision=1.1.1.1&view=markup) uses `Vi`, though not really in a consistent manner it seems... (FYI: you can format it with `groff -man -Tascii vi.1`) ... I *think* it uses `Vi` to refer to the name of the program, and `vi` to refer to the command-line utility...

Comment: The Vim-spell check considers `vi` to be the wrong capitalisation (blue background, not red), and corrects it to `VI`... At first I thought this was because of roman numerals, but it doesn't do that for `iv` or `vii` ... The `nvi` manpage uses `vi` and `nvi` throughout ...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The [2.8BSD manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vi&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=2.8+BSD&arch=default&format=html) does the same.

Comment: But [some other docs](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/contrib/nvi/docs) from `nvi` use both `Vi` and `vi` ... :-/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to definitively ascertain the "correct" spelling of vi. It may be either vi or Vi, I *suspect* vi is probably "more correct", but I personally don't consider Vi incorrect enough to change the title.

I also can't think of any good alternatives. I find "Vim and vi" to be awkward, it's a site about "Vi and clones", Vim is only there because it just so happens to be the most popular clone. Also, our domain name is vi.stackexchange.com; not vim.stackexchange.com.